# how to apply a CSS class to the last element of an array in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

```
<div class="col-12 parent-node" *ngFor="let profile of org_structure?.Parent"
            [ngClass]="(org_structure.Parent) ? 'border-active':''">
```

here I need to apply the class 'border-active' to the last element of Parent array.

Comment: `*ngFor="let profile of org_structure?.Parent; let i = index"`, `org_structure.Parent.length - 1 === i`

Comment: Thanks @DimaS. it is working...

Comment: `<div class="col-12 parent-node" *ngFor="let profile of org_structure?.Parent; let i = index" [ngClass]="(org_structure.Parent.length - 1 === i) ? 'border-active':''">`

Comment: make things more pretty, `[ngClass]="{'border-active': org_structure.Parent?.length - 1 === i}">`

Comment: yeah noted @DimaS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NgForOf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables) directive provides exported values that can be aliased to local variables.

```
 <div
  class="col-12 parent-node"
  *ngFor="let profile of org_structure?.Parent; let isLast = last"
  [ngClass]="{'border-active': isLast}"
></div>
```